# Compare multidimensional two list and fill zero

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have 2 lists as below.

```
list1 = [(271.086, 350.919 , 309.912, 384.286),
         (575.991, 240.076, 644.586, 302.432)]

list2 = [(2.0, 235.0, 17.0, 257.0),
         (21.0, 218.0, 44.0, 247.0),
         (52.0, 264.0, 78.0, 284.0),
         (80.0, 235.0, 100.0, 251.0),
         (173.0, 190.0, 198.0, 211.0),
         (184.0, 174.0, 205.0, 190.0),
         (192.0, 154.0, 211.0, 176.0),
         (254.0, 154.0, 275.0, 182.0),
         (273.0, 348.0, 307.0, 381.0),
         (536.0, 297.0, 617.0, 371.0),
         (573.0, 235.0, 649.0, 300.0)]
```

I want to equal list1 to list2. I assign zero to those who do not have the equivalent of list2 in List1. Finally:

```
list1 = [(0, 0, 0, 0),
         (0, 0, 0, 0),
         (0, 0, 0, 0),
         (0, 0, 0, 0),
         (0, 0, 0, 0),
         (0, 0, 0, 0),
         (0, 0, 0, 0),
         (0, 0, 0, 0),
         (271.086, 350.919 , 309.912, 384.286),
         (0, 0, 0, 0),
         (575.991, 240.076, 644.586, 302.432))]
```

I wrote the code below to do this. But this gives me error 'list index out of range' on line 2 (if block).

```
for i in range (len(list2)):
    if (abs(list2[i][0] - list1[i][0]) == list2[i][0]) 
    and (abs(list2[i][1] - list1[i][1]) == list2[i][1])
    and (abs(list2[i][2] - list1[i][2]) == list2[i][2])
    and (abs(list2[i][3] - list1[i][3]) == list2[i][3])

       list1[i].insert(0,[0,0,0,0])
   else :
       list1[i] = list1[i]
```

I understand that the pyhton for loop doesn't work as in C #. Can you help me with this? If the code I wrote is incorrect, would you write a sample code to achieve my goal? Thank you

Comment: what is the logic in your  `if` statments ? `abs(list2[i][0] - list1[i][0]) == list2[i][0]` ? this will be True only if `list1[i][0]`  is  `0`

Comment: and the elements form `list1` are different from the elements from  `list2` , how did you get your `Finally:`  list?

Comment: List2 is a object detection labels list and each element correspond to the values ​​of X1, Y1, X2, Y2. List1 is predictions list. I try to equalize the number of predictions to the number of labels. In the if block; If the difference between the label and the predict coordinates is greater than the label, this prediction does not belong to that label. So, I add 0 values ​​to my prediction list to be equal to the labels list size.

Comment: it seems like this element  from lsit1 `(271.086, 350.919 , 309.912, 384.286)` with this element from lsit2 `(273.0, 348.0, 307.0, 381.0)` are equal ? how come ?

Comment: This is completely an idea I have produced. Don't hang out on this point. My problem is "for loop"

Comment: please provide accurate data that match your description/scenario, otherwise, everybody will get confused since we can't guess your  mind

Comment: You are right. But, actually, my problem is this: In the for loop, it should make a comparison every iteration and add elements to list1 according to the situation. So I shouldn't get the out of range error until the end of the loop. But in the loop the if value is calculated for each element of list2 at the same time, and therefore i get the error of out of range when i = 3. How can I fix this? For this reason, I said that "Don't hang out on this point". I hope I could explain myself

Answer (score 0):

as far I understand your data should look like:

```
list1 = [(271.086, 350.919 , 309.912, 384.286),
         (575.991, 240.076, 644.586, 302.432)]

list2 = [(2.0, 235.0, 17.0, 257.0),
         (21.0, 218.0, 44.0, 247.0),
         (52.0, 264.0, 78.0, 284.0),
         (80.0, 235.0, 100.0, 251.0),
         (173.0, 190.0, 198.0, 211.0),
         (184.0, 174.0, 205.0, 190.0),
         (192.0, 154.0, 211.0, 176.0),
         (254.0, 154.0, 275.0, 182.0),
         (271.086, 350.919 , 309.912, 384.286),
         (536.0, 297.0, 617.0, 371.0),
         (575.991, 240.076, 644.586, 302.432)]
```

to get your expected result you could use a `for` loop:

```
default = (0,0,0,0)
result = []
for e in list2:
    if e in list1:
        result.append(e)
    else:
        result.append(default)
result
```

output:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (271.086, 350.919, 309.912, 384.286),
 (0, 0, 0, 0),
 (575.991, 240.076, 644.586, 302.432)]
```

or you could use a list comprehension:

```
[e if e in list1 else (0,0,0,0) for e in list2]
```